# Python + Selenium: Using and managing old web drivers

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, browser-automation, test-automation-framework, cross-browser-testing

**Details**

Based on a browser matrix I have to test several browsers, also older ones.

Example: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/creating-browser-compatibility-matrix-for-testing-workflow/

You surely know the problem yourself, that you always have the latest browser versions available, but the test requirements are defined apart from the latest browser versions.

Using a Python Auto Updater and the appropriate package, you can automate this process in Selenium.

Similar to Browserstack or Crosbrowsertesting.com I'm looking for a possibility to include old webdrivers in test cases via Selenium.

Is there a kind of administration or package which covers this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to setup your own cross-browser testing environment you could look at using [Selenium Grid](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_4/setting_up_your_own_grid/), have look here: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/selenium-grid-4-tutorial-for-distributed-testing/

In the grid you install nodes (machines) that contain a fixed version of a browser, where you install a fixed version of the driver.

Maintaining your own grid is time consuming, probably more expensive than using something like BrowserStack which run the grid for you.

Asking the remote webdriver for a version of an OS/Browser will search the Grid nodes to find a suitable Node to run the test on. On the node the driver.exe will be started, etc...

```
desired_cap = {
 'os_version': '10',
 'resolution': '1920x1080',
 'browser': 'Chrome',
 'browser_version': '62.0',
 'os': 'Windows',
}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='https://your_grid/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

This results that in your local code you do not need to manage the drivers anymore.

Comment: This is a very good approach Nils, thank you very much. I am very surprised that this topic is much too little asked for here?